# how to solve connetion with firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

**when i connect with firestore to retrieve some data the command told me this :**

W/Firestore( 6490): (21.3.0) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=The project was disabled or deleted., cause=null}
W/Firestore( 6490): This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

Comment: This is just saying you don't have a healthy internet connection.

Comment: The answer is in the log: "The project was disabled or deleted". Create another Firebase project and replace the google services files.

Comment: I actually DID disable my Firebase app at some point, because it had been hacked... Now I can't find how to enable it again! Anybody who can help?

Answer (score 0):

It means that your mobile app, or specifically the Cloud Firestore client/driver in your app could not make a connection to the server due to unstable internet connectivity.
Maybe you can verify if your device has a stable internet connectivity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean that, you know... It could mean that the app has actually been disabled or deleted!